# Node2D wont display where I want it, even when using script to change its GlobalPosition (C#)

Tags: c#, game-development, godot4

I am trying to display a Node2D which contains text and animation when the player enters an interaction zone. The Node2D I am trying to display, called EToInteract, is displaying, but something is messed up with its position and movement. Here is a [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cWUSByPiwSaNat22haKsaI64Ti0DvT66/view?usp=drive_link) of what happening. You can see that the interact display is on the top left, and its not moving. Or rather, it is static on the screen. In my Interaction Manager, I used the following code:

```
...
Node2D interactDisplay;

public override void _Ready()
{
    ...
    interactDisplay = GetNode<Node2D>("/root/WorldNode/InterfaceManager/EToInteract");
    interactDisplay.Hide();
    ...
}

public override void _Process(double delta)
{
    if (activeAreas.Count > 0 && canIneract)
    {
        ...
        interactDisplay.GlobalPosition = otherBody.GlobalPosition;
        interactDisplay.Show();
    }
    else
        interactDisplay.Hide();
}
```

otherBody is the purple NPC character you see in the video.

And this is the layout of my World Scene

[image: And this is the layout of my World Scene]

I am trying to have the interact display to be on top of the NPC constantly, instead of moving around with the player like you see with the video. I though positioning the display's global position to the NPC's global position would work, but that doesn't seam to be the case. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out my problem was that I had my interact display in a CanvasLayer node, which by default has a property called Follow Viewport disabled. When disabled, its children wont move relative to the screen, but when enabled, it will move along with everything else as the camera moves. I just moved my EToInteract node somewhere else (because I had other important nodes in the CanvasLayer), and that fixed the problem.